# Key Events are not getting detected on iPad ( safari ) if the focus is not on form element

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari

I want to detect the keyDown events on my web page. Everything is fine everywhere except iPad ( safari ). Its getting detected if the focus is on any textelement or dropdown etc.

I tried using tabindex but dont know how exactly its working ( i cant see if the focus is being changed or not. )

How to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: how you can have the keyboard up without clicking on an input on your ipad

Comment: Connecting Bluetooth Keyboard .. that should work right ?, i am not sure though.